# Command line passing quotes within quotes

Tags: command-line, parameter-passing, filepath, argument-passing, double-quotes

I've been searching for a solution to this but couldn't find one. Not sure if its possible.

Can I pass into command-line execution that passes a in a bat file which has an input file as its arguments?

So from the command-line it'll look like this:

```
C:\run.exe "C:\space folder\run.bat "C:\space folder\input.txt""
```

The problem is with the folders that has spaces so the 
quotes are required to be in there.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
C:\run.exe "C:\space folder\run.bat \"C:\space folder\input.txt\""
```

And here is a link that you can see all escape characters
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

Comment: I thought about that, but wouldn't it err on the last address location, I.e. it would attempt to view input.txt/ as a folder?

Comment: No, It parses all line before execute.

Comment: Ahh. Can't one also use UNIX styled directory syntax on windows? E.g. C:/space\ folder/run.bat?

Comment: Yeah, acn, but some batch commands could not execute with this syntaxe. I've had running on issues on this paste time, but I don't remeber right now.

Comment: I see. +1 by the way for reference.

Comment: I tried running that and in my run.exe i just call "echo %1" to see if the whole string got parsed. But i got this in return:
"C:\space folder\run.bat \"C:\space
It cuts off in the space from the input.txt directory

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old topic, but I found the answer and would like to share.

In Windows you don't have to escape the quotes. Just use them normally.

In this case:

`C:\run.exe ""C:\space folder\run.bat" "C:\space folder\input.txt""`

Comment: Are you sure? I made a simple run.bat file with two lines "echo %1" and "echo %2". Then I passed in your suggested string as argument. The first parameter %1 was shown to be ""C:\space   and the second was shown to be folder\run.bat" "C:\space

Comment: echo may be a special case since it's not really disk-based command, but a built-in one.  It may just output everything after it.

Comment: The problem is that there are two different ways to receive command lines, `GetCommandLine()` or `main(int, char**)`. `echo "Hello"` prints quotes while the same received as `args[]` has no quotes.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, all I needed was quotes.

```
winrs -r:MACHINE001 ""C:\Program Files\MyApp\My App.exe" -x "LOTS OF PARAMETERS""
```